# Two lodash set in one function?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, lodash, material-ui

is this possible to make two set function in one condition ? my goal is to create 3 button calling one function.. to change the this.state.status with the preferred condition.

'all' = null  (this is my goal, my params default should be status=null or ' ') and i want my this.state.status: null

' approve ' = approve  ( status=approve) my goal in my this.state.status: approve

'progress' = progress (status=progress) my goal in my this.state.status: progress

```
    this.state = {
      status: '',
    }
  }

//---------------------button sort--------------------------//
  onButtonChange = ( status, value) => {
    setTimeout(() => AppActions.loadingMask(true))

    if (status === 'all')
    {
      _.set(this.state.data, status, null).set(this.state.status, status, ' ')
     // status = null - my goal is the this.state.status: ' '
    }

    else if (status ==='approve')
    {
      _.set(this.state.data, status, 'approve').set(status, this.state.status, 'approve')
       // status = approve - my goal is the this.state.status: approve
    }
    else if (status === 'progress')
    {
      _.set(this.state.data, status, 'progress').set(status, this.state.status, 'progress')
      // status = progress - my goal is the this.state.status: progress
    }
    BookingsTripsAction.getTrips(
      this.DEFAULT_LIMIT,
      this.state.activePage,
      _.get(this.state.data, status, status))
  }


  <Col>
    <Paper>
      <FlatButton label="All" style={{margin: 12, borderBottom:(this.state.status == 'all' ? '1px solid #2196f3' : 0)}} onTouchTap={this.onButtonChange.bind(this, 'all')}  />
      <FlatButton label="Approve" style={{margin: 12, borderBottom:(this.state.status == 'approve' ? '1px solid #2196f3' : 0)}} onTouchTap={this.onButtonChange.bind(this, 'approve')} />
      <FlatButton label="In-Progress" style={{margin: 12, borderBottom:(this.state.status == 'progress' ? '1px solid #2196f3' : 0)}} onTouchTap={this.onButtonChange.bind(this, 'progress')}  />
    </Paper>
  </Col>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use setState

```
if (status === 'all' || status === null)
    {
     this.setState({data:''});
    }

    else if (status ==='approve')
    {

     this.setState({data:status});
    }
    else if (status === 'progress')
    {
     this.setState({data:status});

    }
```

Comment: Thanks Man :) great work Im still Modifiy the this.setState({ data:}) in to this.setState({status:})

Answer (score 1):

From the [reactjs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly) docs:

> Do Not Modify State Directly.

It will not re-render your component. Always use `setState()` for this. Read the doumentation on [how to use state correctly](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly).

Comment: Hi  @trinx are you referring also with the lodash _.set ?

Comment: @MikeVictoria You should not mutate state with anything else than `setState()`. Also no lodash `_set()` because this is also mutating the state directly and does not call all the react logic behind state changes. Read the documentation and do the reactjs tutorial. It's all very well explained there.

Comment: Hi @trinx thanks for the help :) I still new in React JS